# FullText indexes in multiple variable columns

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

I am currently looking into using FULLTEXT indexes in MySQL for search functionality within a web site.

Basically, the user can go to an advanced search page, and select 1 or more columns to search against, e.g. they can search Title, Description and Comments or either only 1 column or a mixture of the three and when they perform the search these selected columns are searched for against the keywords.

I had created 1 index for the title, 1 index for the description and 1 index for the comments and then tried to run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM support_calls WHERE MATCH(Title, Description) AGAINST('+these, +are, +some, +keywords')
```

I got an error from MySQL saying that the MATCH didn't match any fulltext indexes and I found that I need to create an index which included Title and Description together instead of having them in separate indexes.

This is going to add some complexity if this is the case as I am going to have to create an index for every single variation of what columns the user selects. Am I going about this the right away or is there a better solution?

Comment: AFAIK that's a MySQL restriction you can't override. Depending on your needs, you may be able to `MATCH(Title) AGAINST('+these, +are, +some, +keywords') OR MATCH(Description) AGAINST('+these, +are, +some, +keywords')` and use ranks to sort or further filtering.

Comment: This seems to work from the test I've done, I'm a bit worried it may get quite slow but so far so good. Could you make this an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I'm far from being an expert in full text and I don't want to post a potentially misleading or plain wrong answer. For instance, I've just leant that index requirements are different depending on storage engine and boolean/natural mode [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Answer (score 0):

first execute below query and then run your MATCH() query.

```
ALTER TABLE support_calls ADD FULLTEXT (
Title, Description
)
```

Comment: The OP already acknowledges that. The question is about an alternative to creating a new index for every possible column combination.

Comment: you can also use like %word% or any other wild card characters instead of MATCH